# Animate css with jquery: missing subsequent interations

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to set up an animation on a off canvas menu on click on another element. such off canvas menu gets animated once the button is clicked. my code below:

(https://jsfiddle.net/shredder11/fhqsmhdz/13/)

problem:

```
$(".ok_3").click( function () {

    $(".ok_1").css("right", "90%")
    $(".ok_1").css("left", "0px")
  $(".ok_1").css("z-index", "1")
    $(".ok_2").css("opacity", "0.4")

});

$(document).mouseup(f_1);
```

once I run through a cycle (click, menu appears animated, click out to make it disappear), and I click once again on the button, the animation is no longer there. I am not removing classes anywhere so the class should still be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exactly right, you are not removing the class and it is still there!

CSS animations that run once will run when the class is added to the element and then not run again unless the animation class is removed from and then added to the DOM.

An infinitely repeating animation will obviously run endlessly. An animation with iterations will run for the the amount of iterations specified, but to trigger that iterative animation again, you would remove and add the class to the element.

You will require a slight amount of delay between removing the animation and re-adding it so your best option would be to check for the `animationend` event and remove the class at that point. Alternatively remove the class and then use `setTimeout()` to add a delay. Don't chain `removeClass("fadeInLeft").addClass("fadeInLeft")` as there won't be a delay.

Comment: very intresting stuff! it speaks volumes of my inexperience with animations

Comment: Ha, I found out about that the same way you did: when something didn't work. CSS Animations are tricky at first, but get easier, stick with 'em! Great performance benefits using them.